# How to configure Executor in Spark Local Mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, snappy

#### In Short

I want to configure my application to use lz4 compression instead of snappy, what I did is:

```
session = SparkSession.builder()
        .master(SPARK_MASTER) //local[1]
        .appName(SPARK_APP_NAME)
        .config("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec")
        .getOrCreate();
```

but looking at the console output, it's still using snappy in the executor

```
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.codec.CodecConfig: Compression: SNAPPY
```

and

```
[Executor task launch worker-0] compress.CodecPool (CodecPool.java:getCompressor(153)) - Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
```

According to [this post](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/How-to-avoid-use-snappy-compression-when-saveAsSequenceFile-td17350.html), what I did here only configure the driver, but not the executor. The solution on the post is to change the spark-defaults.conf file, but I'm running spark in local mode, I don't have that file anywhere.

#### Some more detail:

I need to run the application in local mode (for the purpose of unit test). The tests works fine locally on my machine, but when I submit the test to a build engine(RHEL5_64), I got the error

```
snappy-1.0.5-libsnappyjava.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found
```

I did some research and it seems the simplest fix is to use lz4 instead of snappy for codec, so I try the above solution.

I have been stuck in this issue for several hours, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my solution here, @user8371915 does answered the question, but did not solve my problem, because in my case I can't modified the property files.

What I end up doing is adding another configuration

```
session = SparkSession.builder()
        .master(SPARK_MASTER) //local[1]
        .appName(SPARK_APP_NAME)
        .config("spark.io.compression.codec", "org.apache.spark.io.LZ4CompressionCodec")
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "uncompressed")
        .getOrCreate();
```

Answer (score 1):

> what I did here only configure the driver, but not the executor.

In `local` mode there is only one JVM which hosts both driver and executor threads.

> the spark-defaults.conf file, but I'm running spark in local mode, I don't have that file anywhere.

Mode is not relevant here. Spark in `local` mode uses the same configuration files. If you go to the directory where you store Spark binaries you should see `conf` directory:

```
spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 $ ls
bin  conf  data  examples  jars  LICENSE  licenses  NOTICE  python  R  README.md  RELEASE  sbin  yarn
```

In this directory there is a bunch of template files:

```
spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7 $ ls conf 
docker.properties.template  log4j.properties.template    slaves.template               spark-env.sh.template
```

fairscheduler.xml.template  metrics.properties.template  spark-defaults.conf.template

If you want to set configuration option copy `spark-defaults.conf.template` to `spark-defaults.conf` and edit it according to your requirements.